# Installing the most recent stable version of nodejs Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

The following portion of Dockerfile installs node, but defaults to v.`4.2.6`, How do I install the most recent stable version `7.4.0`:

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -yqq install \
    apache2 \
    nodejs \ ## nodejs installed here
    php \
    php-mcrypt \
    php-curl \
    php-mbstring \
    php-xml \
    php-zip \
    libapache2-mod-php \
    php-mysql \
    git \
    supervisor \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) you can install it by doing this :

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

So your Dockerfile could be like this :

`RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -yqq install \
    apache2 \
    nodejs \ ## It should be the good version`

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -yqq install \
    apache2 \
    php \
    php-mcrypt \
    php-curl \
    php-mbstring \
    php-xml \
    php-zip \
    libapache2-mod-php \
    php-mysql \
    git \
    supervisor \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash    && nvm install 7.4.0 \
   && nvm use 7.4.0 \
```